# Передать массив выбранных чекбоксов в глобальную область видимости

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-events

Как передать в глобальную область видимости обновляемый при событии 'change' newArray, чтобы с ним можно было дальше работать?

```js
var field = document.querySelector('fieldset');
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');

function getCheckedValues() {
  var newArray = Array.from(input).filter(function (item) {
      return item.checked === true;
    }).map(function (item) {
      return item.value;
    });
  console.log(newArray);
  }

field.addEventListener('change', getCheckedValues);
```

```html
<fieldset>
 <input type="checkbox" value="red" id="filter1">
 <label for="filter1">Красный</label>

 <input type="checkbox" value="blue" id="filter2">
 <label for="filter2">Синий</label>

 <input type="checkbox" value="green" id="filter3">
 <label for="filter3">Зеленый</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: почему бы просто не объявить `newArray` глобально?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с глобальным объявлением `newArray`, поправьте если неправильно понял что требуется.

```js
var field = document.querySelector('fieldset');
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var newArray;

function getCheckedValues() {
  console.log('old:' + newArray);
  newArray = Array.from(input).filter(function(item) {
    return item.checked === true;
  }).map(function(item) {
    return item.value;
  });
  console.log(newArray);
}

field.addEventListener('change', getCheckedValues);
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" value="red" id="filter1">
  <label for="filter1">Красный</label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="blue" id="filter2">
  <label for="filter2">Синий</label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="green" id="filter3">
  <label for="filter3">Зеленый</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: При таком варианте попытка вызвать newArray вне функции getCheckedValues - дает underfined.  А мне нужно передать этот массив в другую функцию.

Comment: @Жека ну так он будет `undefined` до тех пор пока не произойдет `change`, можно например пустым массивом проинициализировать изначально, например `var newArray = [];`

Comment: Да. спасибо, получилось.